# How to use grid.gradientFill

Tags: r, r-grid

I'm trying to use the function grid.gradientFill from the gridSVG package, but unfortunately I'm not able to see a gradient in my SVG output.

I'm not sure if my code is correct or my Browser does not work (Chrome: 35.0.1916.153 m), can you please give some advise?

Here is my R code:

```
library(grid)
library(gridSVG)

lg <- linearGradient(col = c("black", "white", "black"))

x <- c(0.2,0.2,0.35,0.5,0.65,0.8,0.8,0.65,0.5,0.35)
y <- c(0.5,0.6,0.61,0.7,0.81,0.8,0.7,0.71,0.6,0.51)

s <- c(0,0,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,-1)

grid.newpage()
vp <- viewport(width=0.75, height=0.75)
pushViewport(vp)
grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="blue"))
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col=1, layout.pos.row=1))

grid.rect(x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      width = unit(1, "npc"), height = unit(1, "npc"),
      just = "centre", 
      default.units = "npc",
      gp=gpar(col="green", fill = "blue"), draw = TRUE, name = "tom")
grid.xspline(x = x, y = y,shape=s, open=FALSE, gp=gpar(col=NA, fill="darkred"), name="spline")

grid.gradientFill("spline", lg)
grid.gradientFill("tom", lg)

grid.export("c:/@temp/somekindofgradient.SVG")
```

I'm very interested in giving the spline a gradient ...

Any hint is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I found the solution :-)

If you want to use

grid.gradientFill(object, ...)

The object, in my question the grid.xspline(...) object called "spline" does not have to have a fill parameter, meaning ...

Replacing

```
grid.xspline(x = x, y = y,shape=s, open=FALSE, gp=gpar(col=NA, fill="darkred"), name="spline")
```

with

```
grid.xspline(x = x, y = y,shape=s, open=FALSE, gp=gpar(col=NA), name="spline")
```

And there is some beautiful gradient :-)